# Get all Html5 Tags using Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Is there a way to get all html5tags with one command instead of doing this? :

```
int h = (doc.getElementsByTag("canvas").size()
                    + doc.getElementsByTag("audio").size()
                    + doc.getElementsByTag("embed").size()
                    + doc.getElementsByTag("source").size()

                        etc.
```

Comment: I don't think so. Tags do not carry information about their religion  (HTML4/5)

Comment: Parse all tags from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list and then automatically generate list from those and then automatically iterate list and do whatever you were doing with results.

Comment: `doc.getElementsByTag("*")`, because all of the elements are HTML5 elements ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result in one command using the `select()` method. This method allows you to specify multiple selectors, and Jsoup will return unique elements from the document that match any of the specified selectors.

For example:

```
int h = doc.select("canvas, audio, embed, source").size();
```

You can add as many comma-separated arguments as you need (e.g. all of the new elements introduced in HTML5).

Comment: thank you i forgot that i can chose multiple objects with select. Thanks so much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are :

```
all_html5_tags = [ '!DOCTYPE' ,'a' ,'abbr' ,'acronym' ,'address' ,'applet' ,'area' ,'article' ,'aside' ,'audio' ,'b' ,'base' ,'basefont' ,'bdi' ,'bdo' ,'big' ,'blockquote' ,'body' ,'br' ,'button' ,'canvas' ,'caption' ,'center' ,'cite' ,'code' ,'col' ,'colgroup' ,'command' ,'datalist' ,'dd' ,'del' ,'details' ,'dfn' ,'dir' ,'div' ,'dl' ,'dt' ,'em' ,'embed' ,'fieldset' ,'figcaption' ,'figure' ,'font' ,'footer' ,'form' ,'frame' ,'frameset' ,'h1' ,'h2' ,'h3' ,'h4' ,'h5' ,'h6' ,'head' ,'header' ,'hgroup' ,'hr' ,'html' ,'i' ,'iframe' ,'img' ,'input' ,'ins' ,'kbd' ,'keygen' ,'label' ,'legend' ,'li' ,'link' ,'map' ,'mark' ,'menu' ,'meta' ,'meter' ,'nav' ,'noframes' ,'noscript' ,'object' ,'ol' ,'optgroup' ,'option' ,'output' ,'p' ,'param' ,'pre' ,'progress' ,'q' ,'rp' ,'rt' ,'ruby' ,'s' ,'samp' ,'script' ,'section' ,'select' ,'small' ,'source' ,'span' ,'strike' ,'strong' ,'style' ,'sub' ,'summary' ,'sup' ,'table' ,'tbody' ,'td' ,'textarea' ,'tfoot' ,'th' ,'thead' ,'time' ,'title' ,'tr' ,'track' ,'tt' ,'u' ,'ul' ,'var' ,'video' ,'wbr' ]
```